# Maven build failing due to EMMA error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, maven, emma

I am running Maven build along with EMMA plugin. The goal executed is "mvn -X clean site". Tests are executed fine but during instrumentation we get below exception :

> > Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project projectname: failed to get report for org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument (report:emma) on project projectname: Execution report:emma of goal org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add select output from `dependency:resolve-plugins` and relevant section from your pom.xml

Comment: To be specific, I am facing below issue http://sourceforge.net/p/emma/bugs/75/ Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you perhaps using another plugin that overwrites System.out / reassigning it to another output stream? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228427/redirect-system-out-println