# Pig - How to run a script in silent mode?

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

I have this java program, which executes a pig script in MapReduce mode. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;


public class pigCV {


public static void main(String args[]){

PigServer pigServer;
try {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://hdfs://localhost:8022");
    props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:8021");

    pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, props);

    pigServer.registerScript("Desktop/text_v3.pig");

} 
catch (ExecException e) {   e.printStackTrace(); } 
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}


}
```

The problem is that the output is really verbose.

So I would like to know if this is possible to run the script in silent mode.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `PigServer` supports running in silent mode. However, you can write java code to intercept `stdin` and/or `stdout` and then write code to decide which things to print to the screen and which things to ignore or write to a file. There's an example of how to do this in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3234470/2438110).