# Redirecting output in JNA and spwaning childprocess Silently (Without Popup command window)

Tags: java, jna

I have written a java program to spwan child java process. When it spawns child process it opens up a command prompt window and output is redirect to the command prompt. Can you tell me how to spawn/create child process without extra command window and redirect the output of this process to a file. I am using Java 6 and JNA 3.5.2

Below is the command to create process

```
cmd = "c:\\jdk1.6.0_30\\bin\\java.exe -Xmx256m -Xss1024k  -cp <classpath jars>; 
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB com.xyz.test.MainProgram <program arguments>
```

Working code with popup command prompt

`private boolean createChildProcess(ProcessData processData,String cmd,String appName){
        HANDLEByReference childStdInRead = new HANDLEByReference();
        HANDLEByReference childStdOutWrite = new HANDLEByReference();`

```
    int STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100;

    WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference processInformation = new WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference();
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();

    // Create the child process. 
    if (!Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateProcess(
            null, 
            cmd, 
            null, 
            null, 
            true, 
            new DWORD(0x00000020), //new DWORD(0x00000001)
            null, 
            null, 
            startupInfo, 
            processInformation)){
        System.err.println(Kernel32Util.formatMessageFromLastErrorCode(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError()));
        return false;

    }else {
        System.out.println("Created Process :"+processInformation.dwProcessId.intValue());
        processData.setProcessId(processInformation.dwProcessId.intValue());
        //processData.sethProcess(processInformation.hProcess);
        //com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
        com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);
        return true;
    }
} </pre>
```

I tried following code but it didn't work

```
private boolean createChildProcess(ProcessData processData,String cmd,String appName){

    //Tried with Output to file
    HANDLEByReference childStdInRead = new HANDLEByReference();
    HANDLEByReference childStdInWrite = new HANDLEByReference();
    HANDLEByReference childStdOutRead = new HANDLEByReference();
    HANDLEByReference childStdOutWrite = new HANDLEByReference();

    int STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100;

    WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference processInformation = new WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference();
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
    startupInfo.cb = new DWORD(processInformation.size());
    startupInfo.hStdError = childStdOutWrite.getValue();
    startupInfo.hStdOutput = childStdOutWrite.getValue();
    startupInfo.hStdInput = childStdInRead.getValue();
    startupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    saAttr.dwLength = new DWORD(saAttr.size());
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = true;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = null;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
    if (!com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreatePipe(childStdOutRead, childStdOutWrite, saAttr, 0)){
        System.err.println(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
    }

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
    if (!com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.SetHandleInformation(childStdOutRead.getValue(), HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)){
        System.err.println(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());;
    }

    // Create the child process. 
    if (!Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateProcess(
            null, 
            cmd, 
            null, 
            null, 
            true, 
            new DWORD(0x00000020), //new DWORD(0x00000001)
            null, 
            null, 
            startupInfo, 
            processInformation)){
        System.err.println(Kernel32Util.formatMessageFromLastErrorCode(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError()));
        return false;

    }else {
        System.out.println("Created Process :"+processInformation.dwProcessId.intValue());
        processData.setProcessId(processInformation.dwProcessId.intValue());
        //processData.sethProcess(processInformation.hProcess);
        //com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, 0xFFFFFFFF);

        HANDLE inputFile = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateFile(
                "c:\\"+processInformation.dwProcessId.intValue()+".txt", 
                GENERIC_READ, 
                0, 
                null, 
                OPEN_EXISTING, 
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, 
                null);
        //ReadFromPipe(childStdOutRead,childStdOutWrite);
        com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
        com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to create silent process (without console) using following modification in create process option. ***But still need your help for redirecting process output***

```
Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateProcess(
            null, 
            cmd, 
            null, 
            null, 
            true, 
            new DWORD(WinBase.CREATE_NO_WINDOW),
            null, 
            null, 
            startupInfo, 
            processInformation)
```

Answer (score 1):

On windows, invoke `javaw.exe` rather than `java.exe`.  That will avoid the "console" window.

As for redirecting to a file, the easiest way would likely be to pass in a parameter to your Java subprocess to indicate the desired file, and then redirect `System.out` and `System.err` to write to that file.

`System.out` and `System.err` are `PrintStream`s, so on startup you can simply create your own (mapped to a `FileOutputStream`) to redirect all console output.  See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228427/redirect-system-out-println) for details.

Comment: javaw doesn't solve my problem. Please see my answer below for creating silent process.

Comment: Why does running javaw.exe not prevent a console window from showing? BTW, you should edit your original question rather than adding a partial "answer".

Comment: Did you read the StackOverflow link above describing how to redirect the output from the Java process?