# System.out.println to text file

Tags: java, file, output

I was searching a way to get `System.out.println` texts and save them on a .txt file, for example:

```
    System.out.println("Java vendor: " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
    System.out.println("Operating System architecture: " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));
    System.out.println("Java version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
    System.out.println("Operating System: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
    System.out.println("Operating System Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version"));
    System.out.println("Java Directory: " + System.getProperty("java.home"));
```

I want a **.txt** file to the output, any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-redirect-standard-output-to-a-file.html

Comment: @GreyGoose No since the OP seems require to redirect System.out output to a file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect System.out.println](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228427/redirect-system-out-println)

Comment: *"I was searching"* If you really searched, then you would have found on of the many duplicates. So I doubt your statement.

Answer (score 13):

You can do,

```
PrintStream fileStream = new PrintStream("filename.txt");
System.setOut(fileStream);
```

Then any println statement will go into the file.

Comment: I agree. Or he could use a platform-specific solution such as redirecting output to file in bash: java -jar program.jar > output 2> error-output

Comment: Prefer to close obvious duplicate questions, instead of farming reputation.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to declare a `String text` that contains your message you want to output:

```
String text = "Java vendor: " + System.getProperty("java.vendor");
```

Then you can use [**try-with-resources**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement *(since JDK 7)* which will automatically close your `PrintWriter`, when all the output done:

```
try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("texts.txt")  ){
    out.println(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using standard System output stream which writes to console.You need to use PrintStream class,create a file and write to it.Example is below :

[How to write console output to a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994255/how-to-write-console-output-to-a-txt-file)