# How to break loop at some point of iteration and check what system printed out?

Tags: java, junit, while-loop, system

I am trying to find out how can I check what system printed out at some point of iteration during the while loop statement.

I have this method:

```
/**
 * This method counts how much money user inserted
 * If it is not enough to buy chosen cup size it asks user to insert more
 * Otherwise it checks if user does not need the change
 * and collects money to machine based on cup size price
 * This method gets the message from properties file by key identifies
 * add.more.money - if not enough money is in machine
 * user.paid.change - if user put too much to machine
 * user.paid - if user paid the exact amount of money
 * @param constantPrice  - cup size price
 * @return countMoney - how much user put to machine
 */
@Override
public String countMoneyForCupSize(double constantPrice) {
    // constant - price depending on cup size
    String countMoney = " ";
    double sessionMoney = 0;
    boolean flag = true;

    while(flag) {
        if(constantPrice > sessionMoney) {
            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(prop.getProperty("add.more.money"), (constantPrice-sessionMoney)));
            double insertedCash;
            try {
                insertedCash = insertCash();
                sessionMoney = sessionMoney + insertedCash;
                if(insertedCash == 0) {
                    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(prop.getProperty("end.procedure"), sessionMoney));
                    flag = false;
                }
            } catch (InvalidCoinException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }       
        }

        else {

            double change = sessionMoney - constantPrice;
            String makeCoffeeText = makeCoffee();   
            if(change > 0) {
                countMoney = MessageFormat.format(prop.getProperty("user.paid.change"), makeCoffeeText, sessionMoney, change);
            }
            else {
                countMoney = MessageFormat.format(prop.getProperty("user.paid"), makeCoffeeText, sessionMoney);
            }

            collectMoney(constantPrice);
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return countMoney;
}
```

JUnit:

```
@org.junit.Rule
public final ProvideSystemProperty property1 = new ProvideSystemProperty("MoreEuro", "You need more: 0.5 euro");

@org.junit.Test
public void testCountMoneyForCupSize() {
    System.out.println("---------------- Count Money For Cup Size -----------------");
    double largePrice = 1.5;
    double mediumPrice = 1;
    double smallPrice = 0.75;

    try {
        when(machineSpy.insertCash()).thenReturn(1.0);
        assertEquals(machineSpy.countMoneyForCupSize(largePrice), System.getProperty("MoreEuro"));

    } catch (InvalidCoinException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So I want to be clear that If user inserted 1 euro he still needs to insert half a euro more.

Comment: UPDATED junit code

Comment: You probably need to include method signature for `countMoneyForCupSize`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect System.out.println](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228427/redirect-system-out-println)

Answer (score 3):

1) `when(machineSpy.insertCash()).thenReturn(1.0);`

Mocking private method invocation called by the tested public method is not necessarily a good thing as you should mock dependency and not the behavior of the object under test. If `insertCash()` has some specificities that have to be mocked, you should probably move out in another class.

2) About :

> how to break loop at some point of iteration and check what system
>   printed out

Why not just executing a `break` instruction ?

3) `machineSpy.countMoneyForCupSize(largePrice);`

> So I want to be clear that If user inserted 1 euro. He still need to
>   insert half euro more

Rather than trying to test the output written in the console that is not really testing the method behavior, I think that you should change the contract of `countMoneyForCupSize(double)`.

In your actual version the method returns a formatted `String`. It should not.
Logic and rendering tasks are two distinct things.
Mixing both responsibilities violates the Single Responsibility principle (more than one reason to change a class).
Besides, it may prevent from testing the core logic of the method as in your case

Here :

```
if(change > 0) {
    countMoney = MessageFormat.format(prop.getProperty("user.paid.change"), makeCoffeeText, sessionMoney, change);
}
else {
    countMoney = MessageFormat.format(prop.getProperty("user.paid"), makeCoffeeText, sessionMoney);
}
```

You should rather create an instance of a custom class that contains all these data and return it rather than a String.

For example :

```
....
CountMoney countMoney = null;
 ...
if(change > 0) {
    countMoney = new CountMoney(makeCoffeeText, sessionMoney, change);
}
else {
    countMoney = new CountMoney(makeCoffeeText, sessionMoney);
}

...
return countMoney;
```

In your applicative code that invokes `CountMoney countMoneyForCupSize()` you could then call a rendered method (located in a rendering class) that performs the rendering, for example : `String renderingCountMoney(CountMoney countMoney)`.

In this way your design would be better (each class and each method has well defined responsibilities) and you can unit test `countMoneyForCupSize()` without considerations about user text rendering.

Comment: Yes but that method does not stop there. Finally it returns a string formulated from some double values, strings and some static text.

Comment: Ah. You should edit your question with it. It is an important point.

Answer (score 2):

You can check directly that `insertCash` was called multiple times. One way to do this is to to mock multiple calls to `insertCash` with [thenReturn](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.6/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenReturn(T,%20T...)):

```
when(machineSpy.insertCash()).thenReturn(1.0, 0.5);
```

After that you can [verify](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.6/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify(T)) that `insertCash` was called exactly two times:

```
verify(machineSpy, times(2)).insertCash();
verifyNoMoreInteractions(machineSpy);
```

Check out this question for other options:

- [Using Mockito with multiple calls to the same method with the same arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088179/using-mockito-with-multiple-calls-to-the-same-method-with-the-same-arguments)

If you still want to capture and test the output to System.out then you need to redirect standard output. This was already covered in earlier questions:

- [Redirect System.out.println](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228427/redirect-system-out-println)
- [JUnit test for System.out.println()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println)

Comment: But what about breaking a loop when(machineSpy.insertCash()).thenReturn(1.0); If I only inserted 1 is it possible to somehow break that loop cause now the loop will insert 1.0 two times

Comment: @user2204367 well, that's an expected behavior, isn't it? As it's currently implemented, your code will call `insertCash` two times, receive 2.0 and proceed to return change. Is this correct? If you need to insert another value, then pass it to `thenReturn`

Comment: Well u see the thing is that I want to test also if numbers are counted correctly. If I pass argument 1 I get 0.5 to insert more. Maybe i need then extract separate method like countSessionMoney and return double but with each iteration of while loop statement I hope to get the exact number of money to insert more