# How can I get the output of console to my webpage

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am developing dynamic web application using JSP and servlet. One of the methods is to read CSV file. I have done code for reading contents from CSV file. The contents are printed on console, I want this console's output on the web application's window. How can I do it?

Comment: Please share the code where you are reading the file and printing it to the console.

Comment: There are multiple types of logs, which console displays, do you want custom logs that is ones from System.out.print on the browser or something else

Comment: yes from System.out.print, printing on the console and want this output to display on browser

Answer (score 0):

Writing This Code,you can print message in browser.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("message");
```

Comment: where to write it, Is in servlet where im calling Read method to read csv?

Comment: @Dip See how to redirect the stream with [Redirect System.out.println](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228427/redirect-system-out-println) to use the `response` writer. This should be done at the beginning to send every `System.out.printxxx` message in the response stream. From there, not sure how to access them yet ;)

Comment: Yes it is in Servlet.

Answer (score -1):

use Table tag in jsp . In th put your header name  and in Td print your data using loop <%=Your data%>.

Comment: can you please explain in detail..However I dont want to display it by hardcoding..I want to call that output data from console to browser.

Comment: OP want a way to print the value of the output stream into his page. Not some specific instance