# How do i save the output of this code into a file

Tags: java, file-handling

I tried to save the output into a file but it's not working 
please provide me with a solution 
this code prints all the combinations of the given string 
this code works  properly but I'm unable to save this into a file 
I can't copy paste from terminal

```
import java.util.*; 

class psw 
{ 


    static void generate(char[] arr, int i, String s, int len) 
    { 

        if (i == 0) 
        { 

            System.out.println(s); 


            return; 
        } 
          for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) 
        { 


            String appended = s + arr[j]; 
            generate(arr, i - 1, appended, len); 
        } 

        return; 
    } 


    static void crack(char[] arr, int len) 
    { 

        for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) 
        { 
            generate(arr, i, "", len); 
        } 
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; 
        int len = arr.length; 
        crack(arr, len); 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the outputs on the console to a file you can simply redirect System.out like explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228427/redirect-system-out-println).

So all the outputs on the console (that are printed using System.out) are not printed on the console, but in a file.