# How to retrieve the log content from Simplelogger SL4FJ

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2, slf4j

Is there a way to retrieve the contents of the logger when its been passed by reference from a called Class.  I have a simple example program set-up as follows,

Class

```
public class Doubler {

    static SimpleLogger logger;

    public Doubler(SimpleLogger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }


    public int calc(int i) {
        int result = 2 * i;

        logger.info("\ninput is: " + i);
        logger.info("\nresult is: " + result);
        logger.info("summary==>" + "i: " + i + "   " + "result: " + result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Integration-Test (configured in Maven to use the failsafe plugin)
I know this isn't really an integration test but the problem that i am trying to solve is caused by a conflict with re-directing System.out and the fail-safe plugin so I am contriving an example to use it and using a Logger instead of System.out.

```
public class DoublerIT {

    static SimpleLogger logger = SimpleLogger.getLogger(DoublerIT.class);
    Doubler undertest = new Doubler(logger);

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDoubleTheInput() {

        int result = undertest.calc(2);

        if (logger != null && !logger.toString().isEmpty())
            System.out.println("out log>>>" + logger.toString());

        assertEquals(4, result);
    }

}
```

When I run the test via

> mvn verify

it passes but I want to see the output from the logger - see the circle log output in the screenshot below,

[image]

Is there a way that I can retrieve what is inside,
Logger.SimpleLogger@2f7c7260 I am assuming it will be the contents from Doubler i.e.

> ```
>     input is: 2
>     result is: 4
>     summary==>i: 2 result: 4
> ```

I cant find a way from reading the api, [SimpleLogger Api doc](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/apidocs/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html)

I could, reluctantly, consider using a different implementation of the SL4FJ interface, I say reluctantly because our system has already built SimpleLogger into the common library...

the POM.xml is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>logging-poc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>logging-poc</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleloggerlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This question is a bit strange because there is really no reason for your code to be logging anything inside the calc function.  It would be much easier to test things if your calc function was separated from the portion that outputs to the user. This allows you to focus on testing the values returned by functions instead of any system output.  Its also not clear why this simple example needs to read the output at all.

Comment: @Deadron I am trying to solve another, similar problem with some code on a system that i am working on. I need to examine the output of the logs in order to determine whether the tests pass / fail. The logs are currently being written to System.out which I have tried to re-direct to a ByteStream. But this action of re-directing the System.out breaks the failsafe plugin in maven. Thats why I am trying to re-create the problem in isolation and trying to find a solution using a logger.