# Why don't we close `System.out` Stream after using it?

Tags: java, stream, printstream, system.out

I just want to know, we usually close streams at the end, but why don't we close `System.out` PrintStream with `System.out.close()`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you close it you will no longer be able to write to the console, so let's leave this task to the VM when the process terminates. You should only close streams that you own or have manually created. `System.out` is out of your control, so leave it to the creator to take care of.

Answer (score 17):

because we didn't open it the VM did and it's his job to close it unless otherwise documented

it's similar to the C++ adage of I don't own it, don't `delete` it.

Comment: @henning `free` then or in a C++ adage

Answer (score 5):

You can still flush() it, of course.