# Resource Leak Error

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

Evening all. I am a complete beginner to programming with Java, and I am learning about "Scanner", but when I type this basic code into Eclipse, I get a message saying "Resource leak:'scanner' is never closed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
package inputting;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `scanner.close()` at the end of the main method.

Comment: I don't even know what that is. *Starts Crying*        Cheers for all your answers, folks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After finishing using the `scanner`, you must close with the `close` method:

```
scanner.close();
```

The reason why you must close it is because the `Scanner` class implements the [Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface.  Straight from the API:

> A Closeable is a source or destination of data that can be closed. The
>   close method is invoked to release resources that the object is
>   holding (such as open files).

Essentially, if you never close the `Scanner`, then the program will continue to seek for input and keep hold of resources.  Here is a really [simple example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html):

```
    Scanner scanner = null;

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.next());
            //do whatever you need here
        }
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
```

Read more about `Scanner` from the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 2):

Because you are nowhere closing your Scanner. This is problem (classes that deal with I/O should be closed after you're done). You need to close it:

```
scanner.close();
```

So a whole code can looks like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
   // work
}
finally {
   if (scanner != null) {
      scanner.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is some months old but I would like to add: there is no reason to close `System.in` (which closing the Scanner will do) and you probably shouldn't. This is an [automated warning Eclipse is giving](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-avoiding_resource_leaks.htm) related to [Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) and [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) and can be ignored if the underlying resource is `System.in`, `System.out` or `System.err`.

For any other resources, the 'correct' idiom has been shown (to ensure the resource gets closed even if exceptions are thrown).

Pre Java 7:

```
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("some/file"));

    // statements that throw exceptions
} finally {
    if(scanner != null)
        scanner.close(); // also closes the FileInputStream
}
```

And post Java 7:

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("some/file"))) {

    // statements that throw exceptions
}
```

See also ["Why don't we close `System.out` Stream after using it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457723/why-dont-we-close-system-out-stream-after-using-it) The same is true for `System.in`: you shouldn't close a resource you did not open and the VM will handle it when the process terminates.

Answer (score 0):

You have used scanner for getting a input. After using this we should terminate this by:

```
input_name.close();
```

For example in your program, use:

```
scanner.close();
```