# How to create a text file that can be read again?

Tags: java, import

I have taken a basic class on Java, but my knowledge is very little. I have created a text based rpg over the last month or two since I am getting more familiar with Java. I was wondering if there was any way I could have the program create a "save" file to be stored in a certain folder and prompt the user if they would like to open a saved character. I have not learned any of the object oriented parts of Java yet. What could I do to implement this?

Comment: check out the File class, InputStreams, OutputStreams, FileReader and FileWriter. There are some other helpful Readers and Writers which will make reading and writing files easier.

Comment: Start reading the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) where you'll find out how to do all of this and more, including some of the "object oriented parts".

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there was any way I could have the program create a
>   "save" file to be stored in a certain folder and prompt the user if
>   they would like to open a saved character.

Writing and reading a text file is a solid beginner way to save states for games.

There are many ways to [write to files listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java), but here's one example:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");//create the writer object
out.println(text);//write
out.close() //when you're done writing, this will save
```

Now, here's a simple way to read a file [found from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716623/2498729):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"));//objects to read with
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();//use to build a giant string from the file
    String line = br.readLine();

    //loop file line by line
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();//always close!
}
```

There are many tutorials online just a Google away.  |=^]

**NOTE**:  [Always remember to close readers/writers/scanners/etc.  Else wise you'll get resource errors which you can read more about here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317888/resource-leak-error/20317903#20317903)

Comment: @Relytnevir  Some methods in Java will throw Exceptions.  You must tell the code to either let it be thrown or catch it.  There is multiple ways to handle this error.  I would recommend putting a `catch` statement between the `try` and `finally` blocks I have.  There's a lot to read about here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Thank you for your help. Working on this game has helped me with a lot of the topics. I just changed it to use parent and child classes to clean up the code a little.I tried using this code, but it gives me this errror: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. Can you explain to me what is going wrong? @MohammadS.

Answer (score -1):

That’s the class I built to save text,

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Savetext {

    /**
     * Saves text to a <i>.txt</i> file with the specified name,
     * 
     * @param name the file name without the extension
     * 
     * @param txt the text to be written in the file
     * 
     * @param message the message to be displayed when done saving, if <tt>null</tt> no
     * message will be displayed
     */
    public static void Save(String name, String txt, String message) {
        name += ".txt";
        gtxt(name, txt, message);
    }

    private static void gtxt(String name, String txt, String mess) {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        File file = null;
        fc.showSaveDialog(null);
        file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String path = file.getPath();
        path += "\\";
        path += name;

        File f1 = new File(path);
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(f1)));
            wrtxt(out, txt, mess);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage().toString());
        }

    }

    private static void wrtxt(PrintWriter out, String txt, String mess) {
        out.println(txt);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        if (mess != null)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mess);
    }

}
```

you should call the *static save()* method,without making an instance of the class,

Comment: Giving OP chunks of code without explanation isn't a good approach for a beginner...

Comment: right but that’s what I have on the moment,

Comment: @MohammadS.: He's not just posting code without explanation, but worse, he's posting ***bad*** code, including closing the PrintWriter in a different method from where it was created, preventing the ability to re-use it in a loop, or to close it in a finally block, and combining GUI code in the same block as file I/O code, something that should be avoided. Not only that the question has nothing to with GUI or Swing coding.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: doesn’t it work for a simple string to be saved as a .txt file?

Comment: It is terrible code and should not be used as an example for newbies. -1 down-vote.